# How to encode .cap Closed Caption into MPEG video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, mpeg, closed-captions

I have a .cap Closed Captions file and a .mpg video that I want to add this into. I have seen several hundreds examples of how this is done for .srt (subtitles) and any video format using ffmpeg but there is no solution that I could find for .cap.

End goal is converting this video with Closed Caption to HLS stream. There are two ways it could be done, I think:
1. Encode the captions to video first > Then convert to HLS
OR
2. Convert the video to HLS first > Then add closed captions on .ts segments

I could not find a way to include the .cap file though. ffmpeg throws the following error -
`mycaptionsfile.cap: Invalid data found when processing input`

This is the cmd I am using for my video to hls conversion though -
`ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -i myvideo.mpg -vf scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -c:v h264 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 2800k -maxrate 2996k -bufsize 4200k -b:a 128k -hls_segment_filename 720p_%03d.ts 720p.m3u8`

Comment: I see that apparently there is no solution. Is there a way I can convert .cap to .scc format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can only use Cheetah's own converter to convert `.cap` to `.scc` and then take it from there. May be use **CaptionMaker** or **Adobe Premiere Pro**. Trial are available as well for a limited period.

Some reference is here - http://www.theneitherworld.com/mcpoodle/SCC_TOOLS/DOCS/SCC_FORMAT.HTML

, and here - https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2015-August/027936.html